# JSTL absolute URI cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jakarta-ee

When I load my webpage the following error occurs, I'm trying to use jstl:

> The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved
> in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I am using the Apache Tomcat webserver.
This is my pom.xml maven file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.own</groupId>
    <artifactId>Web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my index.jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>For each</title>
</head>
<body>
    Odd numbers up to 20:
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="20" step="2">
        ${i} &nbsp;
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

And my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    
</web-app>
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what is your classpath loook like ?

Comment: I've just uploaded a picture of it (I hope).

Comment: Let Maven produce a WAR file. Is the JSTL JAR there in `/WEB-INF/lib`? If not, then you know the cause.

Comment: it is there in /WEB-INF/lib

Comment: The thing is it is working with JBoss Server 10 (WildFily) o.O

Comment: Real Java EE servers such as WildFly have everything from Java EE bundled, including JSTL. Tomcat is a barebones servletcontainer which only bundles Servlet/JSP/EL/WS.

Comment: I see, thanks! Since then I've been using Wildfly. I thought that Wildfly / Tomcat / Glassfish were on the same level regarding their out of the box capabilities.